# how to find end of quarter given a date in the quarter

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

If i'm given a date (say @d = '11-25-2010'), how can I determine the end of the quarter from that date. I'd like to use a timestamp one second before midnight.

I can get this:

```
select dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()), 0) as quarterStart
```

which gives me: '10-1-2010'

and I use this for one second before midnight of a given day:

```
select DateAdd(second, -1, DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, @d))+1, 0) ) AS DayEnd
```

in the end, a quarterEnd method would give me '12-31-2010 23:59:00'

Comment: what is quarter in this context. for example what output are you expecting when 11-25-2010 as input

Comment: also answered here: http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/6680/how-to-find-quarter-starting-date-and-end-date

Comment: Thanks, @Dave. I did go to that link, but I didn't see the third solution. which is what I was looking for! (it's always in the last place you look, isnt' it?)

Answer (score 3):

i think i got it:

```
select DateAdd(second, -1, DateAdd(qq, DateDiff(qq, 0, getdatE())+1, 0) )
```

Comment: This can also work for other permutations as well. 
*End of last quarter* - remove the +1  
*Last day but not last minute* - change 'second' to 'day'
*Beginning of quarter* - remove the first DateAdd function

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()), 0) as QuarterStart
    , DateAdd(d, -1
        , DateAdd(qq, 1
            , dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()), 0))) As QuarterEnd
```

Just find the first day of the ensuing quarter and subtract a day. If you are using this for a range, then use "strictly less than" and do not substract a day:

```
MyDate >= Dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()), 0)
And MyDate < DateAdd(qq, 1
                , dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
select dateadd(second,-1,
         dateadd(month,3,
           dateadd(qq, datediff( quarter , 0 , current_timestamp ) ,
             0
             )
           )
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Very verbose for clarity. Basically it's direct approach:

- Get year
- Calculate the quarter month considering that there are 3 months in the quarter
- Adjust year for the 4th quarter
- Compile the output

So here is the code:

```
declare @current datetime
set @current = '9-25-2010'

declare @year int
set @year = datepart(year, @current)

declare @quartermonth int
select @quartermonth = ((datepart(month, @current) - 1)/ 3 + 1)* 3 + 1 -- go to the next month

select @year, @quartermonth

-- adjust year if it's 4th quater
select @year = @year + @quartermonth / 12

-- avoid month overflow
select @quartermonth = @quartermonth % 12

select @year, @quartermonth


declare @firstdayofnextquater datetime
select @firstdayofnextquater = convert(datetime, convert(varchar, @year) + '-' + convert(varchar, @quartermonth) + '-01')

select dateadd(second, -1, @firstdayofnextquater)
```